# C# Application not shutting down correctly (still runnning in memory after form closed)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have an odd situation where my application process still lingers in memory after my closing down my main form, my Program.cs code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {    
        [Flags]
        enum MoveFileFlags
        {
            None = 0,
            ReplaceExisting = 1,
            CopyAllowed = 2,
            DelayUntilReboot = 4,
            WriteThrough = 8,
            CreateHardlink = 16,
            FailIfNotTrackable = 32,
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool MoveFileEx(
            string lpExistingFileName,
            string lpNewFileName,
            MoveFileFlags dwFlags
        );

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
        string lockFile = "run.dat";
        if (!File.Exists(lockFile))
        {
            // that's a first run after the reboot => create the file
            File.WriteAllText(lockFile, "");

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
        else
        {
            // that's a consecutive run      
        }
          Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your application create any background worker threads?

Comment: I have same situation here. Working with threads. But one thread needs an "Application.IsShuttingDown" Property but there is no except the ApplicationExit event but the class cannot add this event on each call.

Answer (score 5):

You should only have one Application.Run to ensure there is only one message loop on current thread and avoid the kind of problem you are describing.

Comment: Yes, looks like you're running 2 forms if the conditions are right (although poor indenting of code obscures this). This is definitely non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually indicative of a background thread that hasn't terminated.

Answer (score 1):

If the lockfile does not exist, you get a new "main form" running. I guess Form1 is a hidden form when run.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my situation. Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) for details.

I put the critical part into an own thread. The thread is set to `Thread.IsBackground = True`
Now DotNet manage to kill this thread on application exit.

```
Dim thStart As New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf UpdateImageInGuiAsync)
Dim th As New System.Threading.Thread(thStart)
th.Start() 
th.IsBackground = True
```

[image: Background thread]
Regards